# Print output from JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit

I'am looking for a way to show logs/ results of JUnit tests in Eclipse. My tests are running fine but I have no way to verify if it is semantically correct. I don't need to export reports, just need to check its log. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm very new to Java and Eclipse therefore having hard time to get used to these dev environment.

Comment: what do you mean "semantically correct"? basically, eclipse shows the results automatically, what more do you need?

Comment: by "semantically" I mean it is correctly coded but I am not sure if it was really what I intend. I only see the failure trace to trackback if a test has failed but otherwise I don't see any show log for results @Stultuske

Comment: what log would you need? all tests that ran are indicated. the succesful ones in green, the failing ones in red with a stacktrace. what more do you need?

Comment: omg i mean for example I want to test if a + b = c, I'd love to see if a, b, c have the right values as I intended because I don't hard code the value of a, b, c inside my test but rather initialize them in setup() method and let them change while running all the tests. I have like 20 tests running at the same time.

Comment: I want to see what the test produces and not only if it's green or red flagged

Comment: ... Tests don't actually 'produce' anything. but I guess you could always add print statements in them, to check values during running them.

Comment: You should add a logger over using something like `System.out.println`, but that will enable you to add logging statements and produce the values you wish to see from your tests

Comment: @JoshGordon I don't get your point. How can I add such "logger" ? I want to absolutely avoid using System.out.println all over my tests because that's horrible. Thanks!

Comment: @AnneP I've added an answer that goes over how I'd use logging in your situation. This is how I use logging when I want to output information and I'm not just debugging through my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a Logger such as slf4j, you'd bring the logger into your test class as such

`private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTestClass.class)`

Then create some logging statements to see your values

`LOGGER.info("The value of the thing is: " + variableValue)`

This way you aren't using `System.out.println` all over your code but still get an output in the console when running your tests

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good hint, I'm diving into it :-) (my vote up is not displayed sorry)

Comment: @AnneP no problem if you can't vote up, but if you can accept the answer if it solves your problem that would be great. Thanks